# "On/at/for/over the weekend" in American English

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, american-english

Some sources say that "at the weekend" is wrong, while other ones say it's correct. Which form is acceptable in American English?

> - On Saturdays her sister Ann usually comes to stay with Mary on/at/for/over the weekend/s.
> - What are you going to do at/on/for/over the weekend/s?
> - We are going to Paris on/at/for/over the weekend/s.
> - Are you going to stay here for/at/on/over the weekend/s?

Which preposition do American English speakers use — *at*, *on*, *for*, *over*?

Comment: You don't normally say "at the weekend," not unless _weekend_ is being used as an adjective (e.g., "We saw them at the weekend festival").  The differences between on/for/over are much more subtle and contextual, often (but not always) interchangeable, and probably can't be fully addressed in a comment.

Comment: And you can use *in* when weekend is used as an adjective. For example: *We got involved in the weekend class*

Comment: *in* attaches to ***class*** not *weekend*.

Comment: "You'd better ask such questions at the weekend, when we'll be free."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to admit I haven't consulted any sources, but here is what I'd say is "correct":

- On Saturdays, her sister Ann usually comes to stay with Mary for the weekend.

and

- What are you going to do for the weekend?
- What are you going to do over the weekend?

and

- We are going to Paris for the weekend.
- We are going to Paris over the weekend.

"Weekend" would not normally be pluralized when preceeded by the word "the".  For example:

- Are you going to stay here on weekends?

And finally, to address "at the weekend": this is often seen in British publications, but I've never seen the phrase "at the weekend" in American English.

Comment: I've seen the following sentence in an English course book published by Longman Pearson (New Cutting Edge - Intermediate, 2007): " A lot of people go to the coast at the weekends." Could it be an exception in which the word "weekend" is in the plural after "the"?

Answer (score 19):

As JR says, *at* doesn't work. In general, you would use *at* with a time, e.g., `I'm going to do that at 3 PM`. You can use *on/for/over* for a day or date range, with slightly different meanings. *On* is slightly vague (possibly deliberately so) and would suggest some time during the weekend, or possibly the whole weekend. `For the weekend` could mean most of the weekend and possibly the entire weekend, and `over the weekend` explicitly means the whole weekend — in this context. As @JeffSahol points out, in other contexts (e.g., I'll fix that over the weekend) it just means that by the time the weekend is over it will have happened.

This is based solely on my experience as a native speaker of American English.

Comment: I would qualify what you said about "over the weekend": I can say "I'll fix that over the weekend" and it could mean that I will fix it at some time during the course of the weekend. Also "for the weekend" sounds more like the whole weekend, though not necessarily so, as you said. For example if you are going to "stay for the night" that means all night, not some part of it.

Comment: Does 'on the weekend' also refer to some time during the course of the weekend?

Comment: @Monica - "on the weekend" is definitely not usual American usage.  "On Saturday", "on Sunday" - yes.  "On the weekend" - no.

Comment: @Monica - as MT_Head said, it's not very common, but if someone said, `I'll get that done on the weekend`, it would be to distinguish from getting it done during the week. It might take an hour, or it might take the whole weekend. It also might not get done, of course. :)

Comment: "I don't comment on weekends."

Answer (score 6):

It's worth pointing out that *at the weekend* is fine in **British** English. It means "at some point during the weekend".

> I'm going to wash the car at the weekend.

**Americans** would possibly use ***on*** for this.

> Anne is coming to stay at the weekend —
>   *Anne will arrive during Saturday or Sunday*
>
> Anne is coming to stay for the weekend —
>   *Anne will arrive on Friday or Saturday and leave on Sunday or Monday*
>
> Anne is coming to stay over the weekend —
>   could mean either of the above; it could mean that she will arrive at the weekend and stay for longer.

Comment: Actually Americans (in my regional experience) would normally say:  "I'm going to wash the car over the weekend."  "On the weekend" is not commonly used.

Comment: Thanks. Edited -- I've heard it used, and other answers here mention it.

Comment: Actually, I'd probably say: "_I'm going to wash the car this weekend_." No 2-letter preposition needed.

Answer (score 6):

'**On**', among other meanings, is used to indicate "the day or time when something happens"; so we could say:

> - I planned to do a lot 'on' the weekend.
> - Is your routine the same 'on' weekends?

'**Over**', among other meanings, means "during a period of time"; so we could say:

> - She'll stay with us 'over' the weekend.
> - We are planning to go there 'over' the weekend.
> - They decided to read the papers 'over' the weekend.

'**For**', among other meanings, indicates "the time through which an action extends"; so we could say:

> - Where do you plan to go 'for' the weekend?

'At' doesn't work, this preposition could indicate, for instance, "a part of the day" and "a precise moment," not the entire weekend. (*I have to be at lunch at noon*.)

If you like, we could add another preposition to your examples: 'throughout'.

'**Throughout**', among other meanings, indicates "going on for a while" and "all through"; so we could say:

> - It snowed 'throughout' the weekend.

Comment: Thank  you very much for your replies. I may be wrong, but I noticed that you still use it interchangeably. Am I right?

Comment: @Monica: Much of the time, there is so little difference in meaning, that, yes, they can be used interchangably.  She can stay with us 'for' the weekend, and we can plan to do a lot 'over' the weekend.  Those are fine, too.

Answer (score 4):

Andrew Leach already pointed out that "at the weekend" is acceptable in British English.  I thought this was interesting; the following screen shots are both from Macmillan's online dictionary (for the word *at*, meaning 3), but they one on the left is from their online [British dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/at), while the one on the right is from their online [American dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/at).

There are only a few differences in the entries (the last of which is pertinent to this conversation, although the others are rather intersting as well):

(1) in 3a, it's *match* vs. *game*, and *train* vs *flight*;
(2) in one sample sentence, they've changed Edinburgh to Atlanta;
(3) the example sentence *What are you doing at the weekend?* is omitted from the American version.

[image]

Comment: We'd generally use *match* instead of *game*; and we may well use *plane* instead of *flight* in that sort of colloquial sentence. Interesting that they entirely miss out "at the weekend" in the American version.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I think the main reason for changing _train_ to _flight_ in the U.S. version is that not many people in the U.S. catch trains.  And we generally say _game_ instead of _match_ for most of our more predominant sports, though tennis is always a "match."

Answer (score 1):

American speakers emphatically do not use *at the weekend*, but British speakers emphatically do.

Answer (score 1):

Canadian Standard English same a Standard American. I would say "on the weekend" almost exclusively; I would consider it the most generic PP.

"for the weekend" and "over the weekend" are also common, and preferred by many; otherwise I think they connote the idea of a visit, a stay, or the like, and are somewhat more durative. Thus:

"I'll probably play some tennis on the weekend." (Punctive/Aorist/Single or simple/undefined Aspect)

"I'm staying at my friend's place over the weekend." (Durative)

"at the weekend" is unacceptable. I don't hear this in any North American English, standard or otherwise.