# work 'at' the weekends or work 'during' the weekends?

Tags: expressions, prepositions

I wrote "Many college students work at the weekends."  My colleague changed 'at' to 'during' = Many college students work during the weekends.  Do you feel there is a difference, however subtle?

Comment: Did you look up the prepositions? what did *you* find?

Comment: 'At' is British, while Americans are more likely to use 'on'.  See discussion here:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75466/at-on-the-weekends

Comment: One can also work *over* the weekend and *through* the weekend. Also see *[“On/at/for/over the weekend” in American English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66999)*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a significant difference.

*Works [at](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/at)* is usually used for a place (He works at the telephone company) or solving a particular problem (He's working away at it now).

*Working [on](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on)* (3.a.) is used for times (he works on Mondays through Fridays; he also works on weekends sometimes) and problems (He's working on it now).

During is acceptable, as is *They work weekends*.