# at the weekend, on the weekend or in the weekend?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

which is the right grammatical saying from these, "I will do my work on the weekend", "I do my work in weekends" or "I will do my work at the weekend"?

Comment: Why is "over the weekend" missing?

Comment: You can visit [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75466/at-on-the-weekends?s=2|2.9760) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66999/on-at-for-over-the-weekend-in-american-english?s=3|1.8127). You will see a lot of excellent answers.

Comment: [Some... WHERE over the weekend...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSZxmZmBfnU)

Comment: ...But yes, that would be the right one to use. Overwhelmingly the most common.

Answer (score 7):

The best options are "during" or "over".

> I will do my work over the weekend.
>
> I will do my work during the weekend.

Neither "in the weekend" nor "at the weekend" sound correct. "On the weekend" sounds OK, more so if you're talking about multiple weekends.

> I do my work on weekends.

Comment: I'd so love to give this a +1... I agree with most of the answer, except that "at the weekend" is by far the best phrasing to my (native English) ear.

Comment: @AndyT, native from where? "At the weekend" doesn't sound quite right to my American ear.

Comment: @AndyT Interesting. I've literally never heard "at the weekend". Maybe it's a BrE thing? Where are you from?

Comment: @DanBron; Matt: Aha! Yet another side of the pond issue then! I'm from England. I did intend for "native English" to make that obvious, but I guess it is slightly ambiguous. WS2 (in his comment to [CM2K's anwer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/281552/91730) is also British and prefers "at the weekend".

Comment: I believe *over the week-end* has a different meaning to *at the week-end* (or Am *on the w/e*). It suggests that it is some sort of task or chore which you will deliver on the Monday or thereafter e.g. a piece of homework. One would seldom hear *Are you going to the football match over the week-end* - in fact it wouldn't make sense. I think *over* implies *sometime over* and that the timing is loose.

Comment: @AndyT Sorry, perhaps I should have addressed the above comment to you.

Comment: @WS2 - Really? I'd say it pertains to Matt's answer, not to me. I completely agree with it though, and have already given it +1.

Answer (score 7):

My dictionaries say "at the weekend, at weekends "British English,"on the weekend, on weekends "American English.over the weekend (both).LDOCE,Oxford Collocations Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

I like "this weekend" or "over the weekend".
"My parents are coming to visit this weekend."
"Over the weekend, I am going swimming."