# Difference between "at this weekend" and "this weekend"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

What's the difference between "at this weekend" and "this weekend" when they are used in a sentence. How do we use them correctly?
For example, can I say " I am going to visit my friends at this weekend." OR "I am going to visit my friends this weekend." Which one is correct? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: As best I can tell, it is unidiomatic to use "at this weekend" in any instance other than when saying "at this weekend's _____." Have you seen instances where it is used differently/what research have you done on the topic?

Comment: @choster No it isn't - We say 'at _the_ weekend'. AFAIK nobody says 'at this weekend'.

Comment: @KateBunting Who says "_at_ the weekend"??? Perhaps it's a regional thing, but it sounds very strange to me. Maybe I say it without realizing it, but the only prepositions I'm comfortable using would be _over_ ("I'll get that done _over_ the weekend") and _on_ ("I hate to bother you on the weekend, but...").

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["On/at/for/over the weekend" in American English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66999/on-at-for-over-the-weekend-in-american-english)

Comment: @miltonaut British people say 'at the weekend' (see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weekend ). I was replying to a comment which has now disappeared, which claimed that we British used a different expression.

Answer (score 1):

When we use time adverbs with 'this' /this week, this year, this month, etc./, no preposition is necessary.
You can express the period 'on Saturday and Sunday' with 'at the weekend' /British English/ or 'on the weekend /American English/.

Answer (score 0):

We don’t normally use at, on or in before time expressions beginning with each, every, next, last, some, this, that, one, any, all:

He plays football every Saturday.

Are you free next Monday at two o’clock?

Last summer we rented a villa in Portugal.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time